# Using function & sapply to populate two vectors / output two vectors

Tags: r

I have built a function in r, preceeded by two empty vectors and applied a sapply to run the function:

```
ret1 <- c()
ret2 <- c()

a <- function(x) {

if(arbitrary conditional statement on existing dataframe[x,]) {

ret1 <- append(ret1, operation based on previous conditional statement)
ret2 <- append(ret2, secondary operation based on previous conditional statement)

}
}

output <- sapply(1:10, a)
```

I was hoping running the function would populate the two ret vectors, but that did not work. Instead, I receive a "List of 10" output with single values, which I do not know what they represent.

My goal is to perform the two operations on the values in a data frame based on the condition and output two vectors ret1 and ret2 with the operation done for each row x in the data frame.

Am I misunderstanding something conceptually about sapply?

Should I loop instead? (I've been previously trying to avoid this due to added operational time)

Thank you!

Comment: (1) Never define `ret1`/`ret2` *outside* a function and then rely on them *inside* the function. This can be the source of too many problems to list here. (2) Probably no need for looping, but we know nothing about what you're doing or the output you're expecting.

Comment: It would help immensely if you could provide sample input data and expected output given that sample data. I suggest using a public dataset or build data programmatically (`data.frame(...)`), but if you already have data you can share, then [edit] your question and post the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is a sample, only enough rows/columns to get the point across.